# Run script after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two tabs. On the second I have a submit form. So, If I press the "send" button on the form at the second tab the page gets reloaded and I see the first tab instead of the second.

With this function I can switch the tabs:

```
$("#tab1").prop("checked", false);
$("#tab2").prop("checked", true);
```

And I use this to reload the page

```
location.reload(true);
```

But together it will not work:

```
location.reload(true);
    $("#tab1").prop("checked", false);
    $("#tab2").prop("checked", true);
```

Why? Whats my mistake? Can anybody help me?

**self-answer:**
I didn´t know that "location.reload(true);" resets all - my fail. Thx for the fast answers! "sessionStorage" will be a better way ...

Comment: A page reload resets all javascript (and html) properties to their initial position. It would be the same as refreshing your page (F5)

Comment: could you include the click handler?

Comment: Can you please share the html code of send button ?

Comment: When a page loads, all code executing on the *previous* page is gone.  It's a complete reset to the beginning.  If you want code to conditionally run *sometimes* on page load then you need to identify that condition.  Usually server-side code would conditionally emit this client-side code, for example.

Comment: Ouh, ok, I understand. So I have to try an other way.

Comment: You could use a unique identifier such as `document.cookies`, a `GET` query in the URL, or `sessionStorage` set before reloading the page, pick the best depending on browser support (at least for `sessionStorage`)

Comment: I will try "sessionStorage" - thx!

Answer (score -2):

If you're using `$.tabs()` , you need to make use of the `active` property to do that.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ active: 2 });
```

Comment: How did you know he's using a jQuery tabs plugin?! This a stab in the darkness.